# More performant SQL Delete than using NOT EXISTS?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that is deleting a lot of data from a table as follows.  It uses a while loop based on trying to not destroy the transaction log but the Customers table has about 200 million records in it and it is deleting approx. 2 million.  I was wondering if replacing the NOT EXISTS would help at all.

```
WHILE (1=1)
BEGIN
  DELETE TOP(10000) FROM Customers
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CustomerInvoices WHERE CustomerInvoices.CustomerId = 
  Customers.CustomerId)
  IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
  BREAK
END
```

Comment: [Fast ordered deletes](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/04/how-to-delete-just-some-rows-from-a-really-big-table/)

Comment: Fpr performance help we need to see the query plan (please share via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan) and also please show table and index definitions

Comment: `IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)` could instead be `IF (@@ROWCOUNT < 10000)`

Comment: In theory, creating an index on `CustomerInvoices.CustomerId` should be sufficient. That should make the nested loops fast (linear time).

Comment: @SalmanA - You are incorrect - the identification of 10K matching the `NOT EXISTS` will get catastrophically slower the later the batch irrespective of what indexes exist. It doesn't have any way of being able to magically do just the nested loops for the 10k rows that match the `not exists` as it doesn't know the result of that until it does it. It will need to do 198 million nested loops look ups to find the final batch.

Comment: In the absence of any other predicates the only way a `NOT EXISTS` query can be done is by reading `CustomerId` from `Customers` and seeing if that value does not exist in `CustomerInvoices` - regardless of whether both columns are indexed and whatever physical join type it uses this is still going to trend towards needing to read the entirety of `Customers` before finding 10K matching the `WHERE` as these become more scarce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the number of rows in Customers it needs to check before finding `10000` matching the `NOT EXISTS` grows every batch.

The ratio of matching rows will steadily drop until by the final batch you are scanning the whole 198 million remaining rows to find the last 10,000.

You are doing 200 batches. On average each batch reads 100 million in `Customers` rows (the earliest batches much less and the later ones more more) - this totals to 20 billion rows read over all just from that table and a similar amount in `CustomerInvoices`.

If the execution plan is a serial scan then likely every batch this will go over all the ones already processed *in every previous batch* and found to be not eligible before finally getting to the ones of interest.

You can create a temp table with a sequential integer column...

```
DECLARE @LastRow INT

CREATE TABLE #DeleteCandidates(Id int PRIMARY KEY, CustomerId INT);

INSERT #DeleteCandidates
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()
         OVER (
           ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS Id,
       Customers.CustomerId
FROM   Customers
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   CustomerInvoices
                   WHERE  CustomerInvoices.CustomerId = Customers.CustomerId)

SET @LastRow = @@ROWCOUNT
```

Then write some code to process that temp table in `<batch_size>` chunks of `Id` ranges.

e.g. as below

```
DECLARE @BatchSize INT = 10000
DECLARE @MinId INT = 1

WHILE @MinId <= @LastRow
  BEGIN

      DELETE FROM Customers
      WHERE  Customers.CustomerId IN (SELECT dc.CustomerId
                                      FROM   #DeleteCandidates dc
                                      WHERE  dc.Id >= @MinId
                                             AND dc.Id < @MinId + @BatchSize)
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                             FROM   CustomerInvoices/*WITH (HOLDLOCK )*/
                             WHERE  CustomerInvoices.CustomerId = Customers.CustomerId)

      SET @MinId = @MinId + @BatchSize
  END
```

You still need a `NOT EXISTS` on the actual `DELETE` in case there were inserts since the identification that means a delete candidate is no longer eligible.

You might also consider the `HOLDLOCK` hint to deal with the possibility of truly concurrent inserts whilst the `DELETE` query itself is running.

Comment: Thanks so much everyone this is a huge help I will try some of the suggestions.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you order the temp table by customer id instead of row numbers?

Comment: @SalmanA - Either way it will be orders of magnitude faster than what they are currently doing. Making the clustered index `id` means each batch of 10,000 can be retrieved with a simple range seek. SQL Server can add a sort to the batch of 10,000 rows retrieved from the `#temp` table to get them into CustomerId order if it deems this would be useful (e.g. for a merge join or an [optimized nested loops](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/optimized-nested-loops-joins/ba-p/383537).

Comment: Still, does it not have to match 200mil items vs 10000 items when evaluating the `WHERE Customers.CustomerId IN (` part?

Comment: No - if that is using a nested loops index seek then each batch can just seek exactly the rows needed. So in the end the rows seeked in `Customers` and read by the batched `DELETE` is just 2 million as opposed to 20 billion (assuming the initial state is that rows matching the where are spread evenly through the table) with the  approach in the question. (though there is also the overhead of the initial query to populate the `#temp` table but this is only executed once). I am making the reasonable assumption that `CustomerId` is the PK of `Customers` and will therefore be indexed

Comment: This seems to have drastically improved the performance.  Just going to do some sanity checks that it is removing the same data as before but so far it looks great thanks.